# Gradle cannot resolve local aar dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I wanted to integrate my own library to an Android application.
Before I push it on remote maven repo I want to check the integration with an application locally. So I've pushed it to my `mavenLocal()`.
Maven was installed via `brew install maven`

And there is my problem - Gradle cannot resolve dependency to my library.

Error I get is just `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.op.rlgen:0.0.1`

In library I use `maven-publish` plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.op'
            artifactId 'rlgen'
            version '0.0.1'
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/rlgen-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                // generating pom logic here
            }
        }
    }

    // For `publish` task use mavenLocal
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

to publish a library on my maven I use:
`./gradlew :rlgen:publishToMavenLocal`

In following path i have 2 files, one with `aar` extension, the second one with `pom`:
`~/.m2/repository/com/op/rfgen`

As I thought the problem is caused because of quite complicated scripts in my main app, I created a sandbox, clear Android Application.

In sandbox's gradle I have:

```
// project level
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        // also tried with
        maven {
             url "~/.m2/repository"
        }
    }
}

// app level
dependencies {
     compile('com.op.rfgen:0.0.1@aar) {
         transitive = true
     }
}
```

I check if mavenLocal points to proper folder and it seems ok:

```
// in gradle
repositories {
    println(mavenLocal().url) // file:/Users/op_user/.m2/repository/
}
```

And with this configuration I cannot add dependency to that aar because of:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.op.rlgen:0.0.1:
Affected Modules: app
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that line:
`compile('com.op.rfgen:0.0.1@aar)`. Should be... `compile('com.op:rfgen:0.0.1@aar)`... :D